# How do i pass a complex object to another View in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to pass a complex object (that can be serialized, if that helps) to another view.

Currently this is the code i have, in some controller method :-

```
User user = New User { Name = "Fred, Email = "xxxx" };
return RedirectToAction("Foo", user);
```

now, i have the following action in the same controller ...

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult Foo(User user)
{
 ...
}
```

When i set a breakpoint in there, the code does stop there, but the value of `user` is `null`.
What do i need to do? Am i missing something in the `global.asax`?

cheers :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put your User object in TempData.  You can't pass it as a parameter.

```
TempData["User"]  = new User { Name = "Fred", Email = "xxxx" };
return RedirectToAction("Foo");

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    User user = (User)TempData["User"];
    ...
}
```

Similar to [How can I maintain ModelState with RedirectToAction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279665/how-can-i-maintain-modelstate-with-redirecttoaction#279740)