# How to show error message in asp.net mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Please help me to show Error message in the view. My code is given below -

This is my View Model:

```
public class DepartmentViewModel
{
    //public Department Department { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public string ManagerMemberId { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public List<Member> Managers { get; set; } 
}
```

This is Controller:

```
public class DepartmentController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Department/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var adminUserId = (string)Session["UserId"];
        var memberId = (string)Session["MemberId"];

        List<Department> departments = null;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(adminUserId))
        {
            departments = new DepartmentManager().GetDepartments(false);
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(memberId))
        {
            var companyId = (int)Session["CompanyId"];
            departments = new DepartmentManager().GetDepartments(false, companyId);
        }

        //var managers = new MemberManager().GetMembersOfManagerCategory(true, );

        return View("DepartmentList", departments);
    }


    public ActionResult Delete(string departmentId)
    {
        try
        {
            new DepartmentManager().DeleteDepartment(departmentId);
        }
        catch (System.Exception exception)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "Unable to delete department. Try again,      and if the problem persists see your system administrator.");
            //return RedirectToAction("Index", "Department");
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Department");
    }
}
```

This is View:

```
@model IEnumerable<PDCA.Core.EntityClasses.Department>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Department List";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }
<div class="container">
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <form class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>List of Departments:</legend>
        <table border="1" cellspacing="1">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Id
                </th>
                <th>
                    Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    Company
                </th>
                <th>
                    Manager
                </th>
                <th>
                    IsActive
                </th>
                <th>
                </th>
            </tr>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DepartmentId)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DepartmentName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Company.CompanyName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Manager.MemberName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsActive)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { item.DepartmentId }) |
                        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { item.DepartmentId })
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
        <p></p>
        <p>
            @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
        </p>
        <p></p>
        <p>
            @Html.ValidationMessage("Error");
        </p>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
}
```

In the view I put  @Html.ValidationMessage("Error") but the error message is not shown there.

Comment: Do you have a validation error occurring or are you just wanting to output some error?

Comment: Actually I want to show the error message thrown by the controller in the Department List view.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you have a duplicate form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <form class="form-horizontal">
```

`@Html.BeginForm` takes care of the `form` tags for you.

Secondly, try adding `@Html.ValidationSummary` like so

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <fieldset>
```

Thirdly, you need to reference the correct script files. Typically this would be done in a layout page but that is up to you.

Add references to

```
jquery
jquery.validate.js
jquery.validate.unobtrusive.j
```

CDNs can be found [here](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx)

Assuming you don't enter a `DepartmentName`, press submit and you should see the error message.

Bear in mind that the `model` for your page has to be `DepartmentViewModel`. In your example above it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

You are redirecting, so modelstate is gone. You can save it through tempdata, but I wouldn't go that way ([How do I maintain ModelState errors when using RedirectToAction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658747/how-do-i-maintain-modelstate-errors-when-using-redirecttoaction)). You can show error with special field and some notification message (eg. toastr), or simply stay on the same view and then modelstate errors will show.

```
public ActionResult Delete(string departmentId)
    {
        try
        {
            new DepartmentManager().DeleteDepartment(departmentId);
        }
        catch (System.Exception exception)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "Unable to delete department. Try again,      and if the problem persists see your system administrator.");
            //return RedirectToAction("Index", "Department");
YOU SHOULD ADD MESSAGE TO VIEWDATA HERE, OR RETURN SAME VIEW(make delete POST action also)

        }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Department");
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more please. I did not get you.

Comment: Go to the link in my answer; ModelState is not persisted on redirect. You are caching the error, putting it in modelstate, but redirecting after -> you need to persist modelstate(solutions in link), but I would consider refactoring it. P.S. I'd make a few changes to your code(make delete action Post, get elmah for error logging- with try catch it will be hard to debug...)

Answer (score 0):

try adding the validation summary as also suggested by @glosrob like

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
   @Html.ValidationSummary()
...
```

also use `ValidationMessageFor` like

```
<td>
     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DepartmentName)
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(v=>v.DepartmentName)
 </td>
```