# ASP MVC, URL of partial view is wrong. Need a specific Url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, partial-views

I've been struggling for days now, without any success.

Parent method, return a view :

```
    public ActionResult ContactHome(int currentTab = 0)
    {

        IContactPage content = this.FauxBouchonContactPage();

        Presentation.XXX.Logic.Models.CustomerCare.ContactHome model = new Presentation.XXX.Logic.Models.CustomerCare.ContactHome(content, currentTab);

        return this.View(VIEW_CONTACT_HOME, model);
    }
```

View Code :

```
@switch (Model.CurrentTab) { 
  case (int)Common.XXX.Enums.ContactPageType.BlockType:  @Html.Partial(Presentation.XXX.Logic.Controllers.CustomerCareController.VIEW_CONTACT_CHOSETYPE, new Presentation.XXX.Logic.Models.CustomerCare.ContactType()); break;
  case (int)Common.XXX.Enums.ContactPageType.BlockComplaint:  @Html.Partial(Presentation.XXX.Logic.Controllers.CustomerCareController.VIEW_CONTACT_RECLAIM, new Presentation.XXX.Logic.Models.CustomerCare.ContactReclaim()); break;
  case (int)Common.XXX.Enums.ContactPageType.BlockQuestion:  @Html.Action(Presentation.XXX.Logic.Controllers.CustomerCareController.ACTIONQUESTION, Presentation.XXX.Logic.Controllers.CustomerCareController.CONTROLLERNAME, new { isPost = false }); break;
  // others case
```

I call Html.Action instead of Html.Partial when some actions are required before showing the view, no problems here.

The pattern is the following:

1. First Contact type is called, a partial view with radioButtons to chose Contact or Complaint.
2. Then the partial view Contact or Complaint are displayed.

The problem is the following, when accesing the view contactType wich is the first partial view in the order i get the following url :  `http://xxx.com/fr/CustomerCare/ContactHome?currentTab=1`

Witch is what i want, but when accesing question or complaint, the URLs are :

```
http://xxx.com/CustomerCare/ChooseContactType
```

When pasting this url in a new tab, i will get a 404 error since no routes are defined for my partials views.

Instead of `http://xxx.com/CustomerCare/ChooseContactType` i want to display `http://xxx.com/fr/CustomerCare/ContactHome?currentTab=3` in the url.

How can achieve this ? Or fix my 404 error. I can paste more code if needed.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having trouble with a similar problem, i found my answear here : 
[How do I maintain ModelState errors when using RedirectToAction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658747/how-do-i-maintain-modelstate-errors-when-using-redirecttoaction/740874#740874)

Use RedirecToAction for a correct Url and TempDate to store your modelState.